# How does Google Wallet know what my credit card looks like?

Tags: android-pay

I logged into Google Wallet and when I look at my payment methods, Google has an image of what my card looks like. Is there a database that accessible for online merchants to get this image or are they requesting them from banks themselves?

It's a nice touch for UI that I think would be cool to integrate into projects.

Comment: It is there own database. Only Google has access as it was built by them. Wish we could use it though

Comment: That would be the cameras they installed in your house for the upcoming "Google Room View" product. You may want to get out the heavy duty tape for the one in the bathroom :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, I doubt its an *actual* image of *your card* (+1 for @paxdiablo's comment) rather, likely an (licensed) image of standard bank cards. The number in all credit cards correspond to the type of card (MC, VISA, AMEX, etc) and includes what's known as a [BIN number (Bank Identification Number)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Issuer_Identification_Numbers).

If you have both, and I'll *assume* some permission to use that bank's logo/image of their cards, voila :)